# iOS remote control for Arduino

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, wifi

I am trying to make a wifi remote control for iOS to Arduino to control a small car. My main problem is getting the data for the forward and backwards, left and right to the Arduino over wifi. The way I thought of doing this was to send repetitive http requests from iOS to the Arduino whilst holding one of the buttons. Anyone have any ideas on how I could do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The way I thought of doing this was to send repetitive http requests
>   from iOS to the Arduino whilst holding one of the buttons.

That's one of many ways of doing it, but it is wrong. Why? Sending and receiving data via http request. I've done both this wrong way and the correct way (I'll explain below) in a project that I did long time ago. Arduino to C#.

Now the ideal way of doing what you need to do is to either:

1. Use sockets.
2. Use Telnet.

Both of these are real-time. So you could just hold a button and then transmit the data real-time and continuously to the receiver.

Comment: Thanks. also where you say sockets are you referring to WebSockets?

Comment: Oops, yea. :) Good luck!